# Alphamax Macro expects END MATRIX command

Tags: macros, spss

I try to call the alphamax macro in SPSS but when I try to run the command below, spss expects a 'end matrix' command, but this does not work:

```
  alphamax 'variable names'.

 Or this:

  matrix. 
  alphamax 'variable names'.
  end matrix.
```

I also tried DEFINE/ENDDEFINE but also not working..
Here is the Macro: http://afhayes.com/public/alphamax.sps

Comment: Without information about what the alphamax macro is, it's hard to shed much light on this question.

Comment: http://afhayes.com/public/alphamax.sps

Comment: I also checked the Varnames but they are all correct

Answer (score 0):

I ran this without a problem like this after running the alphamax file to get the macro defined.  No quotes should be used in the invocation.

alphamax x y z.